# Need help to solve this (ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (15,) for Tensor u'Softmax_2:0', which has shape '(?, 54)')

Tags: python, session, numpy

Below is my code for neural network on my own dataset and I got the following error: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (15,) for Tensor u'Softmax_2:0', which has shape '(?, 54)'

I am quite new.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inputX = data.drop(['Name', 'md5', 'legitimate'], axis=1).as_matrix()
inputY = data['legitimate'].as_matrix()
n_samples = inputY.size
n_feature = inputX.shape[1]

inputX = array([[  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   8.45000000e+03,
          8.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   5.32480000e+04,
          1.63840000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   5.40480000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.73440000e+04,   2.08594534e+09,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.09600000e+03,   4.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.37280000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.20607000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.20000000e+02,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   4.00000000e+00,   2.70373594e+00,
          1.05637876e+00,   6.22819008e+00,   1.63840000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.32480000e+04,   1.59390000e+04,
          9.92000000e+02,   5.28640000e+04,   6.00000000e+00,
          1.37000000e+02,   8.10000000e+01,   2.50000000e+01,
          1.00000000e+00,   3.52426821e+00,   3.52426821e+00,
          3.52426821e+00,   8.92000000e+02,   8.92000000e+02,
          8.92000000e+02,   7.20000000e+01,   1.60000000e+01], 
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   8.45000000e+03,
          8.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   5.27360000e+04,
          1.12640000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   5.35300000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.73440000e+04,   2.08699392e+09,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   4.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.37280000e+04,
          1.02400000e+03,   8.92300000e+04,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.20000000e+02,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   4.00000000e+00,   4.31899422e+00,
          3.30769150e+00,   6.15499505e+00,   1.42080000e+04,
          1.02400000e+03,   5.27360000e+04,   1.57382500e+04,
          9.92000000e+02,   5.22730000e+04,   6.00000000e+00,
          1.33000000e+02,   8.10000000e+01,   2.50000000e+01,
          1.00000000e+00,   3.54207119e+00,   3.54207119e+00,
          3.54207119e+00,   8.92000000e+02,   8.92000000e+02,
          8.92000000e+02,   7.20000000e+01,   1.60000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   8.45000000e+03,
          8.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   4.09600000e+04,
          2.04800000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.66080000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.50560000e+04,   1.92151552e+09,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.09600000e+03,   4.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   6.55360000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.21734000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.20000000e+02,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   3.58061262e+00,
          8.04176679e-02,   6.23193618e+00,   1.22880000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.09600000e+04,   1.04442000e+04,
          9.64000000e+02,   3.76480000e+04,   2.00000000e+00,
          6.80000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.12000000e+02,
          6.00000000e+00,   3.00438262e+00,   2.40651198e+00,
          3.59262288e+00,   6.10333333e+02,   1.24000000e+02,
          1.41200000e+03,   7.20000000e+01,   1.60000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          1.10000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   3.54816000e+05,
          2.57024000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   1.83632000e+05,
          4.09600000e+03,   3.60448000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   6.26688000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30880000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   4.59039653e+00,
          2.37894684e+00,   6.29682587e+00,   1.20524800e+05,
          7.68000000e+03,   3.54816000e+05,   1.22148600e+05,
          1.64680000e+04,   3.54799000e+05,   7.00000000e+00,
          1.38000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          7.00000000e+00,   3.91441476e+00,   1.44168828e+00,
          7.67709054e+00,   7.29842857e+03,   1.60000000e+01,
          2.84380000e+04,   7.20000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.71000000e+02,
          6.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.40640000e+04,
          1.64864000e+05,   1.02400000e+03,   1.25380000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   2.86720000e+04,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   4.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.41664000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.27680000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   4.10454072e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.44010555e+00,   6.75840000e+03,
          0.00000000e+00,   2.40640000e+04,   4.62608000e+04,
          3.14400000e+03,   1.54712000e+05,   8.00000000e+00,
          1.55000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          6.00000000e+00,   3.19910735e+00,   1.97133529e+00,
          5.21481585e+00,   4.52000000e+02,   3.40000000e+01,
          9.58000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   1.50000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.18784000e+05,
          3.81952000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   5.99140000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.22880000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   5.20192000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   5.58287000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30880000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   5.66240790e+00,
          4.18369159e+00,   7.96187140e+00,   1.00147200e+05,
          9.21600000e+03,   3.34848000e+05,   1.01559800e+05,
          9.36800000e+03,   3.34440000e+05,   7.00000000e+00,
          1.14000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.80000000e+01,   6.53094643e+00,   2.45849223e+00,
          7.99268848e+00,   1.85234444e+04,   4.80000000e+01,
          3.39450000e+04,   7.20000000e+01,   1.40000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.74592000e+05,
          3.00032000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   1.17140000e+05,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.80224000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   4.87424000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   5.13173000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30880000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   5.73547047e+00,
          4.75826034e+00,   7.36431335e+00,   9.30816000e+04,
          1.53600000e+04,   1.92000000e+05,   9.46988000e+04,
          2.15000000e+04,   1.91664000e+05,   1.10000000e+01,
          2.54000000e+02,   1.50000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.50000000e+01,   5.73239307e+00,   2.85236422e+00,
          7.98772639e+00,   1.27061333e+04,   1.18000000e+02,
          6.05000000e+04,   7.20000000e+01,   1.40000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          9.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   4.75648000e+05,
          3.48672000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   3.19769000e+05,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.83328000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.56064000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   1.82072586e+09,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30880000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   5.13993423e+00,
          4.48079036e+00,   6.55814891e+00,   1.64864000e+05,
          1.38240000e+04,   4.75648000e+05,   1.68145200e+05,
          3.08400000e+04,   4.75580000e+05,   1.40000000e+01,
          4.21000000e+02,   1.50000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.90000000e+01,   2.82782573e+00,   9.60953136e-01,
          7.21232881e+00,   2.63703390e+03,   2.00000000e+01,
          6.76240000e+04,   7.20000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.59000000e+02,
          9.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.57696000e+05,
          6.24640000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   6.70150000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.63840000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.33472000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   2.72988000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30240000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   4.00000000e+00,   4.81988481e+00,
          2.97736539e+00,   6.48512410e+00,   5.50400000e+04,
          3.58400000e+03,   1.57696000e+05,   5.56267500e+04,
          6.70000000e+03,   1.57297000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          7.60000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.30000000e+01,   3.94329633e+00,   1.81444345e+00,
          6.12204520e+00,   2.70815385e+03,   1.32000000e+02,
          9.64000000e+03,   7.20000000e+01,   1.40000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.59000000e+02,
          8.30000000e+01,   8.20000000e+01,   7.24992000e+05,
          2.30604800e+06,   0.00000000e+00,   4.24345600e+06,
          3.52256000e+06,   4.30899200e+06,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.09600000e+03,   5.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   6.70924800e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   3.07704700e+06,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.27680000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   9.00000000e+00,   3.78312500e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   7.99951830e+00,   3.36782222e+05,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.88416000e+06,   7.44182333e+05,
          2.27200000e+03,   3.06129900e+06,   4.00000000e+00,
          2.43000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          2.10000000e+01,   3.98746295e+00,   2.64215931e+00,
          6.47369968e+00,   1.42880000e+04,   7.60000000e+01,
          2.70376000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.20320000e+05,
          3.85024000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   6.15780000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   1.26976000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   5.28384000e+05,
          1.02400000e+03,   5.66330000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.30880000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,   5.64644365e+00,
          4.11726412e+00,   7.96277585e+00,   1.01068800e+05,
          9.72800000e+03,   3.30752000e+05,   1.02623800e+05,
          9.40400000e+03,   3.39652000e+05,   3.00000000e+00,
          8.90000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          6.00000000e+00,   3.72982391e+00,   2.45849223e+00,
          5.31755236e+00,   2.73950000e+03,   4.80000000e+01,
          9.64000000e+03,   7.20000000e+01,   1.50000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.59000000e+02,
          1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   2.33984000e+05,
          1.37779200e+06,   0.00000000e+00,   9.31200000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   2.41664000e+05,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.63020800e+06,
          1.02400000e+03,   1.66150900e+06,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.32800000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   3.00000000e+00,   5.46068132e+00,
          3.13962777e+00,   7.09009944e+00,   5.37258667e+05,
          5.63200000e+03,   1.37216000e+06,   5.39602667e+05,
          1.33160000e+04,   1.37185600e+06,   1.00000000e+00,
          8.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.80000000e+01,   4.32832189e+00,   2.32321967e+00,
          7.06841290e+00,   7.61582778e+04,   9.00000000e+00,
          1.34273500e+06,   7.20000000e+01,   1.90000000e+01],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.71000000e+02,
          6.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   4.91520000e+04,
          5.61152000e+05,   0.00000000e+00,   3.38800000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.32480000e+04,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.09600000e+03,   4.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   6.14400000e+05,
          4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   4.00000000e+00,   3.69925758e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.48297395e+00,   1.94600000e+04,
          1.60000000e+01,   4.91520000e+04,   1.50074000e+05,
          1.60000000e+01,   5.48460000e+05,   4.00000000e+00,
          1.19000000e+02,   1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   2.58000000e+02,
          1.00000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   2.91840000e+04,
          4.45952000e+05,   1.68960000e+04,   1.48190000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   3.68640000e+04,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   5.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          5.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.76537600e+06,
          1.02400000e+03,   5.94294000e+05,   2.00000000e+00,
          3.41120000e+04,   1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   6.00000000e+00,   3.76419176e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.47970818e+00,   7.93600000e+03,
          0.00000000e+00,   2.91840000e+04,   2.92339333e+05,
          2.53600000e+03,   1.28204800e+06,   8.00000000e+00,
          1.71000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          6.00000000e+00,   3.15203588e+00,   2.16096405e+00,
          5.21367450e+00,   3.54333333e+02,   2.00000000e+01,
          7.44000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.32000000e+02,   2.24000000e+02,   3.31670000e+04,
          2.00000000e+00,   2.50000000e+01,   3.78880000e+04,
          1.53600000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+04,
          4.09600000e+03,   4.50560000e+04,   4.19430400e+06,
          4.09600000e+03,   5.12000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.19200000e+04,
          1.02400000e+03,   6.78554440e+07,   2.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.04857600e+06,   1.63840000e+04,
          1.04857600e+06,   4.09600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.60000000e+01,   8.00000000e+00,   2.33301385e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   6.63664803e+00,   6.65600000e+03,
          0.00000000e+00,   3.78880000e+04,   7.19800000e+03,
          8.00000000e+00,   3.77320000e+04,   8.00000000e+00,
          9.60000000e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.40000000e+01,   3.42918455e+00,   2.41356665e+00,
          5.05007355e+00,   7.17142857e+02,   4.40000000e+01,
          2.21600000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   1.50000000e+01]])

 inputY = array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.])

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.000001
training_epochs = 2000
display_step = 50

#define placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_feature])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

#For hidden layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_feature, n_feature]))   
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_feature]))              
y_values1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)       
layer_1_output = tf.nn.softmax(y_values1)  

#For output layer

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_feature, n_feature]))        
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_feature]))              
y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1_output, W1), b1)     
output = tf.nn.softmax(y_values)

# Cost function: Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y - output, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize variabls and tensorflow session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(training_epochs):  

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY})

    if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y:inputY})
        print "Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc) #, \"W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

print "Optimization Finished!"
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY})
print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-017827906dfe> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(training_epochs):
----> 2     sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY}) # Take a gradient descent step using our inputs and labels
      3 
      4     # That's all! The rest of the cell just outputs debug messages.
      5     # Display logs per epoch step

/home/allan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches,feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    765     try:
    766       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 767                          run_metadata_ptr)
    768       if run_metadata:
    769         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/allan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    942                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
    943                 'which has shape %r'
--> 944                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    945           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
    946             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (15,) for Tensor u'Softmax_2:0', which has shape '(?, 54)'
```

Comment: Format your question to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

So your input is of shape (15, 54) and you output is (15,1)
I wrote an answer before but I was wrong. 
Your weights for the output layer should look like this:

```
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_feature, 1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1_output, W2), b2)
```

Because I assume you have 1 output node.

I ran your code and I reshaped inputY:

```
inputY = inputY.reshape([-1,1])
```

It works for me well.
Don't think too much about the -1, it holds the place for the number or samples. And the 1 is actually the shape of your inputY, because you have 1 column for that.
Although, the cost is always 1.0 so I don't know if that is what you want.
Also, I changed the

```
learning_rate = 0.1
```

because I think yours is too small.
And the activation function:

```
layer_1_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_values1)  

output = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_values)
```

With sigmoid I got decreasing cost, I assume is better.
I think 2000 training steps are too many for this amount of data. After 1000 steps it doesn't learn too much. (Use 2000 if you have thousands of samples)
For me, with 1000 steps, the cost is 0.609 at the first steps and 0.421 after 1000 steps.

So your code with my modifications looks like this (my csv file has 10 columns for the input and the 11th column is the output which contains 1 on the first three rows and then 0 on the others... just like yours)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

csv = np.loadtxt('/Users.../table.csv', delimiter = ',')
inputX = csv[:,0:10]
inputY = csv[:,10:]

inputX = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(inputX)

n_samples = inputY.size
n_feature = inputX.shape[1]

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.3
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

#define placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_feature])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

#For hidden layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_feature, 20]))   
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20]))              
y_values1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)       
layer_1_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_values1)  

#For output layer

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20, 1]))        
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))              
y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1_output, W2), b2)     
output = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_values)

# Cost function: Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y - output, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initialize variabls and tensorflow session
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(training_epochs):  

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY})

    if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y:inputY})
        print("Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=","{:.9f}".format(cc)) 

print("Optimization Finished!")

training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY})
print("Training cost=", training_cost, '\n', "W1=",'\n', sess.run(W1),'\n', "b1=", '\n', sess.run(b1), '\n', "W2=",'\n', sess.run(W2),'\n', "b2=", '\n', sess.run(b2))

prediction = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: inputX, y: inputY})
print("Output:\n", prediction)

acc = 1-np.sqrt(training_cost)
print("Acc = ", acc)
```

Comment: Small comment: if you wanna print out the weights, you have to write sess.run(W1) and sess.run(b1) or W2 and b2, as you wish, because the W and b are not defined and you will get error.

Comment: o1 = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: inputX })
o1 = o1.reshape([1,-1])
org = inputY.reshape([1,-1])
print "Actual data : ", org, "\n  Estimated result : ",o1, "\n"

Comment: Hi,
I added the above code to check the accuracy. But it is no where near. Please help me.

Comment: Is your code running now without errors? This is how I calculate the accuracy in the session: mse = cost.eval({x: inputX, y: inputY})
        acc = 1-numpy.sqrt(mse)
        print("MSE = ", mse)
        print("Acc = ", acc).

Comment: Actual data :  [[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]] 
  Estimated result :  \[[  4.29806888e-01   4.29806888e-01   4.29806888e-01   6.89368770e-02
    1.30058471e-02   2.90349312e-03   2.36404268e-03   1.95499510e-03  9.74993873e-03   3.00818626e-02   8.15735944e-03   1.61303822e-02  1.07337579e-01   1.00127864e-03   2.22358882e-04]]

Comment: Hi, 
The above is the result. It is not close to the actual result

Comment: Try tf.random_normal instead of tf.zeros. I also changed the number of hidden neurons to 20. So I have these 2 changes plus I use sigmoid and the training epochs 1000 and I got these values: [ 0.74001521]
 [ 0.81126845]
 [ 0.75619382]
 [ 0.27499411]
 [ 0.26174161]
 [ 0.0431932 ]
 [ 0.04769574]
 [ 0.05554403]
 [ 0.04710874]
 [ 0.04780493]
 [ 0.02711421]
 [ 0.0729734 ]
 [ 0.02849004]
 [ 0.02174402]
 [ 0.02401287]

Comment: I also used "from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler" and 
 "inputX = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(inputX)" to normalize the inputs

Comment: Hi CrisH,
I thank you for your patient. Is there nyway, I can get a copy of your code. I still get even near your result. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I will post it here like an answer. Actually I will edit my previous answer.